# Analyzing split-plot design in lme4 in R

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, glmm, split-plot

I have the data from a split-plot design where A is my whole plot fixed factor with two levels and B is my subplot fixed factor with 2 levels and C is my random block factor. How do I analyse these data to get appropriate the DF (=1 for each fixed factor and interaction) using GLMM in the lme4 package in R?

I tried `response~A*B+(A/B)+(1/C)` which gives the same result as when leaving the (A/B) out of equation completely; thus I am not sure how to incorporate into the equation that the factor B is nested within A. I also tried `response~A*B+(1|C/A/B)` although this is probably wrong, but all the codes are giving me different results and I cannot tell which one seems correct as there are no DF in the summary and the visual output of my data is not so straight forward.

Can anyone help with nesting? Also if I should decide my fixed factors are in fact crossed rather than nested (still have to re-think that), would the code look different?

Comment: Crawley 2012 (The R Book) gives a good explanation on this topic.